# In OpenTK, multiple meshes are not transforming when imported using Assimp

Tags: opengl, blender, opentk, collada, assimp

I'm sure there is an answer to this on the web but I can't find it.
I'm importing a scene from Blender that has multiple meshes, into OpenTK.
The library I'm using to import is Assimp-net, and the file format is Collada (.dae).

I have created a spaceship with multiple parts, each part being a mesh.
Now when I import and draw, the geometry of the objects looks fine and materials work as expected. However, the different parts are not rotated, scaled, or translated as they appear in Blender. What happens is the different parts are not connected, and some appear larger/smaller than they should, in the wrong place etc.

Is there a setting I'm missing when I export from Blender, or is there some Assimp member/function I can use to transform the meshes before I render them?

Importing the file:

```
string filename = @"C:\Path\ship.dae";
Scene ship;

//Create a new importer
AssimpImporter importer = new AssimpImporter();

//This is how we add a configuration (each config is its own class)
NormalSmoothingAngleConfig config = new NormalSmoothingAngleConfig(66.0f);
importer.SetConfig(config);

//Import the model
ship = importer.ImportFile(filename, PostProcessPreset.TargetRealTimeMaximumQuality);

//End of example
importer.Dispose();
```

Drawing the meshes(entire "RenderFrame" event handler in OpenTK):

```
// Clear color/depth buffers
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    // Define world space
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Ortho(-15.0, 15.0, -15.0, 15.0, 15.0, -15.0);

    // Rotate around X and Y axes for better viewing
    rotateX(xrot);
    rotateY(yrot);

    GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);

    var rootnode = wes10.RootNode;
    foreach (Node node in rootnode.Children)
    {
        //for each node, do
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);  //ensure your current matrix is the model matrix.
        GL.PushMatrix();              //save current model matrix so you can undo next transformations;

        var meshIndices = node.MeshIndices;

        if (meshIndices == null)
            continue;
        else
        {
            Matrix4d convertedTransform = new Matrix4d();
            getConvertedMatrix(node.Transform, ref convertedTransform);
            GL.MultMatrix(ref convertedTransform);

            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
            foreach (uint i in meshIndices)
            {
                Mesh mesh = wes10.Meshes[i];

                Material mat = wes10.Materials[mesh.MaterialIndex];

                // Material setup                        
                var spec_color = mat.ColorSpecular;
                var amb_color = mat.ColorAmbient;
                var diff_color = mat.ColorDiffuse;


                float[] mat_specular = { spec_color.R, spec_color.G, spec_color.B, spec_color.A };
                float[] mat_ambient = { amb_color.R, amb_color.G, amb_color.B, amb_color.A };
                float[] mat_diffuse = { diff_color.R, diff_color.G, diff_color.B, diff_color.A };

                float[] mat_shininess = { 0.0f };

                GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Specular, mat_specular);
                GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Ambient, mat_ambient);
                GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Diffuse, mat_diffuse);
                GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Shininess, mat_shininess);

                foreach (Face face in mesh.Faces)
                {
                    foreach (uint indice in face.Indices)
                    {
                        var normal = mesh.Normals[indice];
                        var pos = mesh.Vertices[indice];
                        //var tex = mesh.GetTextureCoords(0)[v];
                        //GL.TexCoord2(tex.X, tex.Y);
                        GL.Normal3(normal.X, normal.Y, normal.Z);
                        GL.Vertex3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z);
                    }
                }
            }                            
        }

        GL.PopMatrix();
    }


    GL.End();                    

    game.SwapBuffers();
```

Updated to use suggestions.

Comment: there is surely a model transformation matrix defined for each mesh or at a higher level that you miss.

Comment: No matrix operation are allowed between begin - end. your begin should stands just before faces parsing loop...

Comment: I must admit I feel a fool, you are correct. Updated original post-moved the call to GL.Begin. Now, the meshes are being transformed-they look thin (scaled on Y axis) but otherwise unchanged. Probably a problem with the tranformation matricies. I will try to resolve and let you know

Comment: The MultMatrix call is indeed working. I also had to do something in Blender: Center the cursor at the center or the 3d world, the select each mesh and go to "Transform->Origin to 3d cursor". This will setup the transformation matrices for each mesh correctly EXCEPT for meshes that have been rotated, which is still giving me issues. If I get those figured out, I'll post how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [c example](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/samples/SimpleOpenGL/Sample_SimpleOpenGL.c), there is a transformation matrix per node...

```
aiMultiplyMatrix4(trafo,&nd->mTransformation);
```

Check this:

- [Data structure](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/doc/datastructure.xml)
- [scene graph](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/assimp/assimp/master/doc/AssimpDoc_Html/AnimationOverview.svg).

If you don't know what to do with that matrix, check [this](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) to learn about matrix stack. (Be aware that modern OpenGL recommand to implement your own transformation matrix)

Golobaly, you need the folowing steps for rendering (read the c example for details):

```
//for each node, do
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);  //ensure your current matrix is the model matrix. 
glPushMatrix ();              //save current model matrix so you can undo next transformations;
glMultMatrixf(Transformation);//apply your node matrix

//render your node, in your example it's surely a mesh

glPopMatrix ();               //restore model matrix
```

Comment: Hmm for some reason it didn't work...I'm using the GL.MultMatrix() function in OpenTK. The matrix I give it definitely has values, but appears to have no effect.